# Declaring a global structure causes a segmentation fault but when localized it is fine?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, global-variables, local-variables

As the title suggests, when I declare structure `BasicSetup_S` globally, I get a segmentation fault. But if I move `BasicSetup_S` into `CallFunction()` the segmentation fault goes away.

The output is correct each time. It produces exactly what I expect to see but I get the segmentation fault. But, if I move the `BasicSetup_S` structure inside `CallFunction` the segmentation fault goes away. Is there any reason why?

I'm thinking that my entire program may use too much memory causing a fault when I declare more global variables.

> For ease of reading, I simplified the names of everything and showed only the useful parts of the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stdint.h"

typedef struct BasicSetup
{
    uint16_t A;
    uint16_t B;
    uint16_t C;
    uint16_t D;
    uint16_t E;
    uint16_t F[3];
    uint16_t G[7];
}BasicSetup;

BasicSetup BasicSetup_S = {
    // A,               // B,
    1,                  2,
    // C,               // D,
    3,                  4,
    // E,               // F[2],[1],[0]
    5,                    6 , 7 , 8,
    // G[6],[5],[4],[3],[2],[1],[0]
    9 , 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15,
};

void CallFunction(uint8_t *writeBuffer, int begAddress, int endAddress)
{
    int i;
    uint16_t tempVal;
    int StartingPoint = 0;

    for (i = begAddress; i < endAddress; i++)
    {
        // Grabs information from Device Information Structure
        if (i >= 0 && i <= 7)
        {
            // Grab Value
            tempVal = *((uint16_t*)&BasicSetup_S.A + i);
            // Send Value
            writeBuffer[(StartingPoint)++] = tempVal & 0xFF;
        }
        else if (i >= 13 && i <= 19)
        {
            // Grab Value
            tempVal = *((uint16_t*)&BasicSetup_S.G + i - 13);
            // Send Value
            writeBuffer[(StartingPoint)++] = tempVal & 0xFF;
        }
    }

    return;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int numOfBytes = 0;
    int i = 0;
    uint8_t writeBuffer[256];

    CallFunction(writeBuffer, 0, 8);
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) printf("%d, ", writeBuffer[i]);
    printf("\n");

    CallFunction(writeBuffer, 13, 19);
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) printf("%d, ", writeBuffer[i]);
    printf("\n");

    CallFunction(writeBuffer, 19, 20);
    for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) printf("%d, ", writeBuffer[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show us the calls please.

Comment: The problem is you're **accessing an array out of bounds**.

Comment: What is the meaning of e.g. `*((uint16_t*)&BasicSetup_S.A + i)`? What is that supposed to do? Are you trying to use the whole structure as an array of `uint16_t` elements? Why don't you use an actual array? What is the use-case for such a thing? What is the actual problem? Are you sure the compiler haven't added any padding between any of the members?

Comment: Also, the order in which you think the array members `F` and `G` are initialized is wrong.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `*((uint16_t*)&BasicSetup_S.A + i)` is supposed to grab the address of that pointer and dereference it so I get the value inside of its address block. Thank you for responding so quickly

Comment: @Rayaarito C doesn't work like that. The behaviour is undefined for the same reasons as outlined in the duplicate.

Comment: Also could you actually consider producing a [mcve]. Because this is not one.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala when I simplified it to what is seen in the above edit, the segmentation fault goes away but it's still the same format as my original code that's giving me an error. Does that mean it has to do with the size of my program? Since what's in the OP doesn't produce the error, should I delete it now?

Comment: @Rayaarito are you really getting `SIGSEGV Segmentation violation` or some other error? The error is relevant

Comment: To conform with the Q&A nature of StackOverflow, your question should consist only of a question. You can add your own answer to your own (open) question. If your closed question is NOT resolved by the duplicate, then you can ask to have your question re-opened. Otherwise, leave it as is and move on.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour of your code is undefined.

You cannot use pointer arithmetic (of non-`unsigned char` type) to reach other scalar members in a `struct`. For staters, you are assuming there is no padding between the members.

Why not use a single array instead?

```
typedef struct BasicSetup
{
    uint16_t m[15];
} BasicSetup;
```

The C standard insists that the array data are contiguous, and pointer arithmetic is then perfectly well-defined.

Comment: "You cannot use pointer arithmetic to reach other scalar members in a struct" Sure you can, this is perfectly fine, although there might be padding anywhere. There is no UB, given that all access is aligned.

Comment: @Lundin. No, you can't. You can take the address of a scalar, or set a pointer one beyond it. But you can't dereference a pointer obtained in the latter manner. What makes you think otherwise?

Comment: @Lundin not again. Of course there is UB because the standard says so.

Comment: Bathsheba is right, @Lundin.  Pointer arithmetic is defined only within the array into which the pointer points, with scalars treated as one-element arrays, and with the exception that a pointer to the element just past the end of the array can be computed (but not dereferenced).

Comment: What I mean is this `for(uint8_t* ptr = (uint8_t*)&my_struct; ptr < (uint8_t*)&my_struct + sizeof(my_struct); ptr++)`, which is supported by normative 6.3.2/7: "When a pointer to an object is converted to a pointer to a character type, the result points to the lowest addressed byte of the object. Successive increments of the result, up to the size of the object, yield pointers to the remaining bytes of the object."  This, assuming `uint8_t` counts as a character type.

Comment: @Lundin: Indeed, `unsigned char` pointer arithmetic is fine. I've put that in.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Not again indeed. Which standard, which you aren't quoting, are you on about this time? Me I'm talking about the standard ISO 9899:2011 "Programming Languages - C", chapter 6.3.2.3/7.